# AppCache correct settings for Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, html5-appcache

I'm trying to figure out which are the correct settings to enable appcache on android webview. I found many discussions about that but none of them worked.

Given that AppCache is set correctly (it works on chrome), my wrong settings on the webview are the following:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.myapp.com");
```

Any idea of why it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you please describe what is not working? What are you expecting, and what is happening instead?

Comment: What I expect: my app working offline. What I get: the app does not work offline, but it does correctly on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 21):

FOUND THE SOLUTION:

The app cache path wasn't set correctly. I'm now using the follownig code to define the path:

```
String appCachePath = activity.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
webSettings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
```

Instead of the old version:

```
webSettings.setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
```

Hope will be useful for other developers :)

Comment: It was useful for me, thank you so much, it came in handy

Comment: webSettings.setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
is deprecated in version 33. solution please ?

Comment: @Imrankhan what is the solution for `webSettings.setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");` because I am getting error here, please do some help?

Comment: @ninja use the  webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

Comment: Oka, I have done like that